# What is the bound of $T(n) = T(n-2) +n\log(n)$?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I am given the following recurrence relationship:
\begin{align}
T(n) &= T(n-2) + n\log(n),  \\
T(1) &= T(0) = \mathrm{constant}.
\end{align}

I need to find the order for the recurrence.

So, using the iterative methodology, what I have until now is as follows:

\begin{align}
T(n) ={}& T(n-2) +n\log(n)   \\
={}& T(n-4) +(n-2)\log(n-2) +n\log(n)   \\
& \vdots   \\
={}& T(n-2k) +\sum_{i=0}^{n/2} (n-2i)\log(n-2i)  \tag{where $2k=n$}   \\
={}& T(0) +\sum_{i=0}^{n/2} (2i)\log(2i)  \tag{reversed order}
\end{align}

I am unsure as to how to progress from here on with the summation. I believe it should be along the lines of $(n^2)\log(n)$ but cannot seem to conclusively prove it. The reason I say this is because for large $n$, the quantity $(n-2i)\log(n-2i)$ can be roughly estimated to $n\log n$, can it not?

Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/97693/24265: $ \sum_{k=2}^n k \lg k \leq \frac{1}{2} n^2 \lg n - \frac{1}{8} n^2.$ (also interesting http://math.stackexchange.com/q/121997/24265)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow a sloppy estimate and switch to integration:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n/2} (2i)\log(2i)  \approx  \int_0^{n/2} 2x\log x\,\mathrm dx,$$ which will yield $n^2 \log n/4 - n^2/16 = O(n^2 \log n)$. So your solution is right.